# Returning script not working in XMLHttpRequest.responseText

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have two pages with the same script. It's working on one of them, but it's NOT working on the page, where it displayed through responseText.

My HTML PHP Page in which I'm using the XMLHTTPRequest

```
var ajaxRequest;
try
{
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
// Internet Explorer Browsers
try
{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)
{
    try
    {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
    }
}
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
{
    document.getElementById("ajaxresult").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
    return false;
}
}
var queryString = "?atype=" + stype + "&amode=" + smode + "&afrom="+sfrom+"&ato="+sto;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax/get_act_statement.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
return false;
```

My Response Text Was working fine, I display the invoice numbers with details, having a view invoice link, while clicking invoice link I need to open a modal box to show the invoice details. The problem is that it's not OPENING modal box but it's navigating to the other page and showing the invoices.

I have checked the modal box script in other page, without using ResponseText. It's working fine.

Here is the returning code from my php file

```
$display_string = "<h4>Result</h4><div class='category-desc clearfix'></div><table class='category'><thead><tr><th width='12%' nowrap='nowrap'>Invoice No.</th><th width='13%' nowrap='nowrap'>Date</th><th width='15%' nowrap='nowrap'>Payment Mode</th><th width='25%' nowrap='nowrap'>Despatched By</th><th width='20%' nowrap='nowrap'>Destination</th><th width='5%' nowrap='nowrap'>Amount</th><th width='10%' nowrap='nowrap'></th></tr></thead><tbody>";
        $i=1;
        while($ac_getting_result_payment_purchase = mysql_fetch_array($purchase_query))
        {
            if($i == 1)
            {
                $display_string = $display_string."<tr class='cat-list-row1'>";
            }
            else
            {
                $display_string = $display_string."<tr class='cat-list-row2'>";
                $i = 0;
            }
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='12%' nowrap='nowrap'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['TrnsNo']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='13%' nowrap='nowrap'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['TDate']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='15%' nowrap='nowrap'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['PaymentMode']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='25%' nowrap='nowrap'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['Despatchedby']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='20%' nowrap='nowrap'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['Destination']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='5%' nowrap='nowrap' align='right'>".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['Amount']."</td>";
            $display_string = $display_string."<td width='10%' nowrap='nowrap' align='right'><a class='modal' href='../coding/showti.php?type=hinvoice&id=".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['TrnsNo']."'>View Invoice</a></td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
        mysql_close($con);
        $display_string = $display_string."</tbody></table>";
echo $display_string;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Even though you put a lot of effort into your question, you missed some inportant things: 1. What is the error you are getting? (If you see no error, you are not using the right tools. Check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) 2. What is the difference between the working file, and the non-working one? 3. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've copied your code and tried it, and the ajax call works as expected, returning a response to the div. So there must be some more code/other code that's causing a problem. One thing might be the query string. Where are all those variables defined? If this has a flaw in it, it might request something differently than you expect.

Comment: @nfechner: Thanks for your comment. Working file, is just another php file, I put the same code <a href="www.example.com" class="modal">hi</a> Its working pretty fine(ie example.com opens in a modal window) over there, when i get the same link code from ResponseText its not working. Still I get everything clear, responseText gives me back everything fine to display. Other than this link is working. i.e., opening in new page instead of opening in modal window.

Comment: @kasimir Im getting the responseText good for display. Its displaying things pefect. But when i try to click the view invoice link its NOT opening in new modal window, instead opening as normal hyperlink.

Comment: I think I got what your problem is, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the link that has to open the new modal window:

```
<a class='modal' href='../coding/showti.php?type=hinvoice&id=".$ac_getting_result_payment_purchase['TrnsNo']."'>View Invoice</a>
```

When it is like this, it's a 'plain' link. So it will open a new page. You have to 'ajaxify' it in order to open the modal window. This means attaching an event listener to it in your javascript, so when you click it, it will run an ajax request and return the response in your modal window div. You can do that inline, like so:

```
<a class="modal" href="#" onclick="doAjax();" />
```

The hash (`#`) is commonly used to prevent the browser from opening up a new page. The `onclick` will execute the function `doAjax` which you define in your javascript file. The `doAjax` will do something like `ajaxRequest.open('get', '../coding/showti.php?type=hinvoice' + querystring, true)` etc. just like you did with your initial ajax request.
You might want to take a look at a framework, like jQuery or Mootools, to implement this further because they make handling ajax request a lot easier and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks :) Let me try using OnClick. I think this would solve my problem. Wonderful hint. Get back to you.

Comment: Its working now, I used OnClick event to do the thing i needed. Thanks a lot for such a wonderful hint.